# Delphi 7 and Microsoft Access 2013 "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed."

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, ado, ms-access-2013

I'm having a problem with a program I am attempting to link to a Microsoft Access 2013 Database. In the program I have the following code in a unit which links the database to Delphi:

```
unit udbSrc;

interface

Uses DB, ADODB, Forms;

Var DBDataBase : TADOQuery;

Procedure OpenDB;

implementation

Procedure OpenDB;
Begin
DBDataBase := TADOQuery.Create(Application);
DBDataBase.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=' + '''DataBase.accdb'';Persist Security Info=False';
end;

end.
```

In the main unit I have the following code under the click of a button:

```
DBDataBase.Close;
DBDataBase.SQL.Text := 'Select * From tblPlayerInfo';
DBDataBase.ExecSQL;
DBDataBase.Open
DBDataBase.First;
```

When I click the button the program doesn't run with the following error message:

> Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.

And it identifies the error to lie in this line of code:

```
DBDataBase.ExecSQL;
```

I have done research and downloaded and installed AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 which did not have any effect. If anyone could please suggest a solution.

Comment: It looks to me like you are adding quotes to Data Source, this is not usual in a connection string https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: @Fionnuala In previous programs on a different computer with MS Access 2010 installed i used the exact same connection string with the only difference being instead of saying: DBDataBase.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=' + '''DataBase.accdb'';Persist Security Info=False'; I would say DBDataBase.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=' + '''DataBase.mdb'';Persist Security Info=False';
end;

Comment: You must have the a 32-bit version of ACE installed. BTW, you should not use `ExecSQL` with the `'SELECT'` statement. use `Open`.

Comment: @kobik Thank you. The problem lay in the fact that I was running 64-bit version of ACE when I should have been running the 32-bit version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you have downloaded and installed **AccessDatabaseEngine_x64**, but this is the 64-bit provider.  Delphi 7 produces 32-bit executable and therefore requires 32-bit providers.  This is why you are getting the provider not found error.  The required 32-bit provider is not installed.

[Download and install **AccessDatabaseEngine.exe**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/download/details.aspx?id=13255) (*not* the **_x64** version) to obtain the 32-bit provider you require.

Typically when there is a choice of 32 or 64-bit versions of software the 32-bit version will be identified as `x86` and the 64-bit version as `x64`.  Having said that, in this case only the **x64** version is explicitly identified in this way with the "plain" name being the alternative version only implicitly.